# List all traits implemented by a type in a scope

Tags: rust, diagnostics

For the sake of making debugging easier and such, I would like to know all traits implemented for a type within a certain scope. Can I get `rustc` to provide me this information? If so, how?

Comment: Run rustdoc over it and you’ll see all traits implemented for a type; that leaves you to determine which are in scope.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rustdoc`/`cargo doc`.

`rustdoc` creates a section with all trait implementations for a given type. [For example with `Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#implementations):

[image: <code>Vec</code> example]

If you would like to do this for your own crate, you might find `--document-private-items` to be useful. See also [How to generate documentation for private items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52136276/how-to-generate-documentation-for-private-items/52136357#52136357).

Comment: While `rustdoc` is useful my question was looking for a shortcut to getting the intersection of: traits implemented by a type, and traits that are in a given scope (from e.g. blanket imports). This gets the former; it is undoubtedly useful information (especially with it reporting satisfied blanket implementations), but not what I was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a janky method for getting this information during development, using autocomplete (I came here hoping for something a little more robust than autocomplete, but have not found it yet).

Using a JetBrains IDE with the rust plugin, within the desired scope, I can pull up an autocomplete list of fields/methods for any type by typing:

```
<NameOfType>::
```

[image: List of autocomplete options for "<&mut i32>::"]

The traits they implement will be listed alongside the methods when applicable:
[image: Autocomplete suggestion that reads "borrow(&self) of Borrow"]

So, you can scroll through that list and hopefully locate the traits you're looking for. Not great, but works in a pinch.