# How to generate documentation for private items

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustdoc

I have a project with:

```
main.rs
module_1/mod.rs
module_2/mod.rs
module_2/module_3/mod.rs
```

when I run `cargo doc`, I have just documentation for `main.rs`, not for modules.

In my `main.rs` I have:

```
mod module_1;
mod module_2;

fn main() {
...
}
```

I have tried documenting modules using  `///` or `//!`.

I can't find in `rustdoc`'s help how do that.

Somebody can explain me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because those modules are private, and the default behavior is to document public members only.

As of [Rust 1.29.0](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/09/13/Rust-1.29.html), `cargo doc` supports `--document-private-items`, to document private items.

Before 1.29, `rustdoc` already supported the flag `--document-private-items`, which means you could generate documentation for your project using `cargo rustdoc -- --document-private-items`, but `cargo doc` did not support the flag.

Comment: Hu, it seems documenting private items is now default (at least in 1.60). But then I would expect a command `--do-not-document-private-items`