# Is it possible to list all the traits implemented for a particular type (variable)?

Tags: rust

Is it possible in Rust to list all traits implemented for a type (variable)? For instance, for learning purposes I want to know all the traits (including marker traits) implemented for a closure, e.g., like this:

```
fn main() {
    let int_value: i32 = 1;
    let string_value = String::from("Value");
    let my_closure = || {
        let moved_string_value = string_value; 
        println!("{}: {}", moved_string_value, i);
    };
    list_traits(my_closure);
}
```

My understanding is that at compile time, the compiler knows the type of the closure (unique anonymous type) so it may somehow detect the information about all the traits implemented for this type and store that data in some structure that can be later displayed at runtime.

Comment: To what extent? Because technically any type count implement an indefinite amount of traits. So are we talking only imported traits, or?

Comment: This is not that simple I think - bear in mind that for example, I can make a new crate and implement a trait for, say u64. If I don't import and use that trait, will the compiler know? What if the trait is private? At a given point, the compiler will definitely know of all traits "in scope". It might not know of others. Also this list changes as scope changes across compilation. I suspect you want the union of all of those lists, but I don't think the compiler provides that to us. It may have it internally (as it can hint when you are missing a trait import), but I wouldn't guarantee it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List all traits implemented by a type in a scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623243/list-all-traits-implemented-by-a-type-in-a-scope)

Comment: @vallentin Yes, at least I would like to know about the used ones. I understand that it's impossible to get all of them if they are not used. Regarding my example, at least I would like to know if the closure anonymous type implements Copy or Clone traits.

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed I know about this approach, however, I do not know how to apply it for an anonymous closure type.

Comment: @RichardMatheson As I mentioned, at least I would like to know about the traits that are "in scope" as you say.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question is closed as duplicate, however, the reference question does not provide the answer to my problem. I have provided concrete example what I want to achieve and for particular case (anonymous closure type), but it seems that it's easier just to mark the question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Yury This question was closed because of the title "list all the traits implemented for a *particular type*". Try editing your question to be more specific to an anonymous closure which you do not know the concrete type of, and your question should  be reopened